# Angular using ui.router injection issue

Tags: angularjs

I have built a simple angular and am trying to implement ui-router and specifically, $UrlRouteProvier.otherwise to redirect to a certain url if something nonexistent is entered. I am getting the following exception when trying to load my page now and can't seem to find the error. All help is appreciated. Code and error below.

Angular app:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/browse/overview.html');
}])
```

error:

```
Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.4/$injector/nomod?p0=gcIm...
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:21:334
    at a (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:20:483)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:21:218
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:35:76
    at r (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:34:428)
    at Lb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:38:146)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js:17:339
```

note: everything works fine if I remove `ui.router` from the list of dependencies

Comment: Unrelated note: version 1.3.4 of Angular is quite old. You'd better use the most recent version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have ui-router code loaded. Try to include:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

Comment: Make sure to load the ui-router library before you reference it in your Angular code

Comment: @m1gu3l I accepted your answer because it fixed the error however routeproverider.otherwise is not redirecting to the page I specified. I am getting an empty page with not found on it when entering a random url such as http://localhost:8081/browse/overvieasdsw.html

Comment: I assumed it's not complete solution and you focus on injection problem. Try to define state with __templateUrl__ pointing to browse/overview.html and then redirect to that state's url. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your config line like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
```